# Warning: Unknown property: "my-property"

Tags: eclipse, javafx, javafx-8, efxclipse, javafx-css

I have a `Node` subclass where I have defined my own `CssMetaData`. Let's say with this metadata my node has a `my-property` property. So naturally, I would use it like this in my stylesheet:

```
.myNode
{
    my-property: 100;
}
```

It is definitely working. But Eclipse is giving me the unknown property warning.

1. How do I remove this warning?
2. Is there any way for me to integrate my custom properties into the CSS editor, such that it can suggest these custom properties when I am typing in?

I'm currently using Eclipse Neon (4.6.1), and e(fx)clipse 2.4.0.

Comment: e(fx)clipse has a [community forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/), you might wish to try cross-posting this there.